# Do any MQTT clients actually reuse packet identifiers?

Tags: mqtt

The packet identifier is required for certain MQTT control packets (http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v3.1.1/csprd02/mqtt-v3.1.1-csprd02.html#_Toc385349761). It's defined by the standard as a 16bit integer, and is generated by each client. The identifiers are reusable by the client  after the acknowledgement packet is received. So the standard allows up to 64k in-flight messages. In practice, the clients I've looked at seem to just increment a counter, and so allow a total of 64k messages to be sent by a client. Both of rust MQTT client libraries panic when that counter overflows. (**UPDATED 2016-09-07**: if the rust clients are compiled in release mode then they don't panic, the value of the Packet Identifier becomes 0 -- in normal circumstances this will work, but...)

Does anyone know of an MQTT client that allows more than 64k messages/client (i.e. re-uses packet identifiers)? I'm wondering if this is a limitation that I need to be aware of in general, or if it's just a few clients. I've taken a quick look at compliance tests and haven't yet seen much to indicate that this is checked -- I'll keep looking.

**Edit**: It could be that some clients achieve this as a side-effect of limiting the number of in-flight messages. **UPDATE 2016-09-07** the rust clients do it by assuming they can wrap on overflow and never catch up to lagging messages (maybe a good bet, but not assured, and with an ugly outcome if it happens)

Comment: You may do better asking this on the paho mailing list as they own what are effectively the definitive set of clients. https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/paho-dev

Comment: Good idea, thanks. I'll ask on a couple of mailing lists.

Answer (score 2):

As you have pointed out, the packet identifier are intended as temporary value that must persist until the published packet is received and acknowledged.

Once acknowledged, you can reuse the identifier (or not).

Most client runs on embedded system and they don't track more than a single packet (so only a single identifier is being handled) since they wait for ACK or REC/COMP before making any other publishing.

So for these clients, even a single identifier would be enough.
Please notice that for QoS 1, remembering the identifier is futile since it's valid to resend the packet if the next packet is not an ACK (so you have the identifier to reply with in the packet you are receiving).

For the rare clients that do support interleaved publish packets, they only need to support 2 valid identifiers at any time (that is, in the case they have received a QoS 2 packet, answered with PUBREC and then receive another QoS 1 or 2 packet).
Once they receive a PUBREL packet they can reply with a PUBCOMP without needing to remember the identifier (it's in the PUBREL header), so the only time they do need to remember identifier is between the PUBLISH and the PUBREC packet. Provided they allow interleaved publish packets, the only case where a second identifier is required is when they are publishing while receiving a published packet at the same time.

Now, from the point of view of the broker, most implementation use a 16-bit counter *per* client so they could support, in theory, up to 65535 in-transit packets.

In reality, since the minimum size of a publish packet is 8 bytes (usually more), that means having to store at least 9 bytes per *potential* packet (the additional byte is for remembering the current state in case of QoS 2) so that's half a MB of memory in the minimal case, but likely much more in real life, since you never have an empty publish payload and topic name.

As you see, it's almost impossible for an embedded system to implement with such storage requirement so shortcut are taken.

In most scenario, either the server does not allow so many un-acknowledged packet (by simply replying to the client in order to release the identifier) or use the identifiers pool between different clients.

So typically, again, the worst case for the broker can only happen if the client does not acknowledge the published packets. If the broker does not get any answer from the client it can:

- close the connection
- refuse to send new published information or
- ignore the answer and republish

All of these strategies needs to be implemented anyway since you could have the same issue with a slow client and a fast publisher **and your 65535 identifiers**.

Since you have these strategies, there is no need to waste a MB of memory per client and instead cut your leg much earlier (while keeping a reasonable working condition).

In the end, the packet identifiers are a tool to deal with *identification* of recent packets, not a tool to *index* all packet received. A counter is good enough for this case and a wrapping around should not pose any issue when you account for the memory and bandwidth requirement.